# Unable to load System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.2.0.0 using rabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nuget-package

So, we are updating our RabbitMQ dll at a project that is perfectly working from RabbitMQ 5.0.1 to 6.2.1 and I cant use the Factory.CreateConnection() method, as it gives me an inner exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Packages.config

```
  <package id="System.Threading.Channels" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net461" />
```

tried reinstalling nuget packages but same trouble.
Do any one have some tips what can be? Checked both versions of project (with old Rabbit Client vs new), Factory object seems to be exactly equal (with some different propierties, of course), so dont really know what to do.

Only found out a slightly difference on the IEndPointResolver(Top one is with the new version of RabbitMQ).

[IEndPointResolver_Difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uT75.png)

PS: Using C# on Visual Studio 2017

Thanks for any advice given =)

Answer (score 0):

Check the executing application's config file (web.config for WebForms or ASP.NET MVC or app.config for WinForms apps). You may have a `bindingRedirect` entry that's forcing the app to a specific version. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

If that's the case, either remove the entry altogether (assuming all class libraries and your dependencies have the same version of `RabbitMQ.Client` or update the redirect to your new version.

Comment: Did not worked :/
Had some but not for RabbitMQ or System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.
Tried removing the entries just in case, but no case u.u

Comment: Try adding one, then.